# Unix bash script run program in background using screen

Tags: bash

It's been a while since I've worked with Unix commands, I want a simple .sh script to run detached using screen that will call another .sh script using screen which will be detached as well and I want the original script to continue to run through the rest of its program. Both scripts should be able to run when the terminal is closed.

My idea is to use this in programA.sh

```
screen -dmS ProgB bash programB.sh
```

And at the terminal I use this to run programA

```
screen -dmS ProgA bash programA.sh
```

I've got the first program to run and show up in screen -ls
but the second program doesn't show up.

Any ideas on why it failed?

Comment: `//` is not a valid Bash comment.

Comment: I know, It's not actually in the code, I just couldn't remember the actual comment, but you recognized it as a comment.

Comment: whats your problem here? Does this approach have any problem?

Comment: Well, it was untested at first, I was hoping to get some useful comments by the time I got to a computer to run it. I found some errors and have modified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can alternatively use:

```
setsid yourCmd
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of that.